# Why is there an undefined/hidden element in my form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I have 3 inputs in  a form.  However when I serialize the data using `funciton is()` there is a 4th field found in the array at element 0.  I can fix this by just looping starting at 1, but does anyone know what this is?

The debug output from IE looks like this

```
"undefinedf0a=on&f0b=&f0c="
```

for var b.

f0a, f0b, and f0c are my input names, "undefined" is the concern here.

```
function is(a)
  {
  var b;
  var c = document.forms[a].elements;   
  // test_input_signup(list)
  if(1)
    {
    for(i=0;i<c.length;i++) 
      {     
      b += c[i].name+"="+c[i].value+"&"; 
      }
      b = b.slice(0, -1)
    }
    return b;
  }
```

Comment: Just curuios as i might learn something, what is the purpose of if(1){}?

Comment: Could you please post the HTML code of the form, it can be a form field with no `name` attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize `b` to an empty string:

```
var b = '';
```